# Is it possible and how to reduce the dimensions of ELMO embeddings using tf-hub elmo model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, elmo

I am using ELMO model from tensorflow hub.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3", trainable=False)
```

The default output dimension is 1024. Is there any possible way to reduce the dimension of ELMO embeddings to `128` without using PCA/losing information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ELMo` is pre-trained models released by **allennlp** these will give the fixed output dimension based on the training which is of **1024**.

One way to reduce the output dimension is by trying dimensionality reduction techniques like `PCA`,`tSNE`, `UMAP`, but as you said it will be at the cost of losing information.

Instead, you can train the `ELMo` from scratch, provided with a good amount of data and devices to train.
You can follow [this](https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/elmo-for-contextual-word-embedding-for-text-classification-24c9693b0045) article which explains about training `ELMo` from scratch.
To change the hyperparameter like output dimension and other things can be done in this [file](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf/blob/master/bin/train_elmo.py).